# Using spread syntax and new Set() with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I am using following code to get unique numbers:

```
let uniques = [ ...new Set([1, 2, 3, 1, 1]) ]; // [1, 2, 3]
```

However, typescript report following error: *Type 'Set' is not an array type.*
I am not typescript ninja, could someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: I think that's just a Typescript bug, if the version you're using claims to support ES2015.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry about that, I should include version of tsc which is 1.6.2

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is a missing feature. TypeScript only supports iterables on Arrays at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I will use .filter() or something else to get job done. I also found few issues on github about this particular error. I will keep an eye on this in future releases.

Answer (score 169):

**Update**: With Typescript 2.3, you can now add `"downlevelIteration": true` to your tsconfig, and this will work while targeting ES5.

The downside of `downlevelIteration` is that TS will have to inject quite a bit of boilerplate when transpiling.  The single line from the question transpiles with 21 lines of added boilerplate: (as of Typescript 2.6.1)

```js
var __read = (this && this.__read) || function (o, n) {
    var m = typeof Symbol === "function" && o[Symbol.iterator];
    if (!m) return o;
    var i = m.call(o), r, ar = [], e;
    try {
        while ((n === void 0 || n-- > 0) && !(r = i.next()).done) ar.push(r.value);
    }
    catch (error) { e = { error: error }; }
    finally {
        try {
            if (r && !r.done && (m = i["return"])) m.call(i);
        }
        finally { if (e) throw e.error; }
    }
    return ar;
};
var __spread = (this && this.__spread) || function () {
    for (var ar = [], i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) ar = ar.concat(__read(arguments[i]));
    return ar;
};
var uniques = __spread(new Set([1, 2, 3, 1, 1]));
console.log(uniques);
```

This boilerplate will be injected once per file that uses downlevel iteration, and this boilerplate can be reduced using the `"importHelpers"` option via the tsconfig.  (See [this blogpost](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/06/30/typescript-2-3-downlevel-iteration-for-es3-es5) on downlevel iteration and `importHelpers`)

Alternatively, if ES5 support doesn't matter for you, you can always just target "es6" in the first place, in which case the original code works without needing the "downlevelIteration" flag.

---

**Original answer:**

This seems to be a typescript ES6 transpilation quirk .  The `...` operator should work on anything that has an iterator property, (Accessed by `obj[Symbol.iterator]`) and Sets have that property.

To work around this, you can use `Array.from` to convert the set to an array first: `...Array.from(new Set([1, 2, 3, 1, 1]))`.

Comment: @Restam : Does typescript provide polyfills for Array.from in IE if "target":"es5" in tsconfig.json ?

Comment: @jackOfAll No, Typescript doesn't do any polyfilling of prototypes for you.  If you set "target": "es5" it should give you a compiler error if you attempt to use a method that needs to be polyfilled.

Comment: @Restam great solution with `Array.from`. Most other people seem to just give up on this. thanks for a real solution!

Comment: It's not a bug, they just don't support it for the `es5` target (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4031). `Array.from` should work if you have `es2015` or higher (`es2017`, `esnext`) in your `lib` list in tsconfig.

Comment: @SimonHänisch Thanks for the link: I've updated my answer, I no longer call it a "bug", but a "transpilation quirk", which is probably a more accurate term.  I also added information about the downlevel iteration option from that link, which also solves the original issue.

Comment: I think IE has a problem with Array.from(someSet)

Comment: @AlejandroB. Yeah, `Array.from` is an ES6 feature that's not supported in IE.  `Set` is also an ES6 feature, so I didn't think that would be an issue, but apparently IE has partial `Set` support.

In that case, I'd suggest the `downlevelIteration` solution.

Comment: We had this problem with IE at work yesterday and fixed it doing `Array.from(theSet.values())`

Answer (score 131):

You can also use Array.from method to convert the Set to Array

```js
let uniques = Array.from(new Set([1, 2, 3, 1, 1])) ;
console.log(uniques);
```

Comment: What's the point of spreading the array only to recapture it in a new array?

Comment: If not possible to target "es6", in tsconfig. And using Set with spread operator is required, how would you do it?

Comment: The point is that if you use `Array.from()`, you no longer need the spread operator. It just adds overhead. `let uniques = Array.from(new Set([1, 2, 3, 1, 1]));`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen the whole reason for above code is to make an array with unique values of original array

Answer (score 42):

In Javascript:

```
[ ...new Set([1, 2, 3, 1, 1]) ]
```

In Typescript:

```
Array.from(new Set([1, 2, 3, 1, 1]))
```

In React State (setState):

```
setCart(Array.from(new Set([...cart, {title: 'Sample', price: 20}])));
```

Answer (score 21):

You need to set `"target": "es6",` in your tsconfig.

Answer (score 12):

Now, you can use `Set` in your Typescript setup (No need to target `es6`):

In you `tsconfig.json`, add this line:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    
    "downlevelIteration": true,                  /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To make it work, you either need "target": "ES6" (or higher) or "downlevelIteration": true in the compilerOptions of your tsconfig.json .
This resolved my issue and working good or me.Hope it will help you also.