# Javascript Set invalid array lenght with ts-node

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig, ts-node

I am writing to ask a clarification on a strange behaviour occurred today while working:

I am working on a Node JS application written by someone else in plain javascript. I started introducing typescript incrementally, very gradually.

I started by installing typescript as a dependency, adding a tsconfig.json file and translating some little file from .js to .ts. Everything worked well, untill a strange problem came out only in a specific point of some absolutely untouched code.

The problem happens here, on line 44

[image]

As you can see in the following screenshot, `this.data.roles` is an array of strings

[image]

On that line the error I get is this one

[image]

1. The problem happens only if I run the application with ts-node. If I run the code using just note it works properly. Can it be something related to my tsconfig.json?

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "isolatedModules": true, 
        "strict": false, 
        "esModuleInterop": true, 
      },
      "include": [
        "node_modules",
        "src"
      ]
    }
```

2. If I change the code to this it works

`const uniqueRoles = [...this.data.roles];`

What can be the cause of such behaviour? This is just for personal knoweledge since the problem is solved :-)

Comment: Why not use `Array::from`?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464504/using-spread-syntax-and-new-set-with-typescript

Comment: Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33464709/4952551