# How to get distinct objects from an array of objects with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Similar question but with javascript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript). Accepted answer

```
const data = [
  { group: 'A', name: 'SD' }, 
  { group: 'B', name: 'FI' }, 
  { group: 'A', name: 'MM' },
  { group: 'B', name: 'CO'}
];
const unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.group))]; // [ 'A', 'B']
```

However if you try the same thing with typescript you get an error *ts2802* **Type 'Set' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher**

How can you achieve the same results with typescript?

**Question two**
How about you want to get unique objects rather than strings . For eample if you want to get

```
[
  { group: 'A', name: 'SD' }, 
  { group: 'B', name: 'FI' },
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using spread syntax and new Set() with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464504/using-spread-syntax-and-new-set-with-typescript)

Comment: see [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects) if you're looking to remove duplicate objects, not just values. (you'll need to read through all the top-voted answers to find the answer that works best for your use case, but I would look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56768137/13762301).

Comment: Also, don't add a second question to an already answered question. (you do realize that TypeScript is just a superset of javascript? The above linked answer needs just superficial typing to be valid in TypeScript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your issue:

```
const array = Array.from(new Set(data.map(item => item.group)));
```

Note: Spreading a Set has issues when compiled with TypeScript. It's safer to use Array.from above instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just use compilation target in your `tsconfig.json` as ES6 or higher:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES6"
}
```

Your current target must be ancient, hence the error.

Other than that, your original code is perfectly correct.